# Storing Hashed Passwords for Docker and Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, password-management, hash

What is the best way to store passwords and use them in Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml. Can I store the secrets in a hashed format and make use of it, So that no one can read my real passwords even if they have physical access. Or else, is there any alternative way to achieve something similar...

Comment: Use them for what?

Comment: For Docker and Docker-Compose

Comment: What are the passwords ***actually*** used for? Repeating that you use them for docker and docker-compose is repeating the headline of your question. Please describe the problem you're attempting to solve in *some more detail*. A hash is for instance not useful if you need to send the *password* somewhere.

Comment: It can be anything containerized. However, mostly I think password variables are required for  databases such as mysql. I am looking for a common solution.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me even after reading your comments, and I don't you'll get any good answers unless you spend some time to [edit] it so it better explains what passwords you're talking about.